# Send C# Application Logs to Linux Syslog Server

Tags: c#, linux, exception, syslog, rsyslog

We have a centeralized Syslog server on Linux. The Company has asked me to send our project logs to this server.

**How can I send my C# application logs to Linux syslog server? Is it possible?**

Answer (score 3):

try using log4net, it offers a RemoteSyslogAppender

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html

below an example of configuration

```
<appender name="RemoteSyslogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender">
 <facility value="Local6" />
 <identity value="MyApp[%level][%property{log4net:HostName}]" />
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message" />
 <remoteAddress value="yourAddressHere" />
</appender>
```

Comment: What about rsyslog.conf? is there any configuration required?

Comment: no, you should just enable inbound traffic to your syslog server
but it should already be configured properly